# Google sheets. Change cell value based on chekbox

Tags: google-sheets

I’m looking script or formulas or guideline for next task in Google sheets: If checkbox is cheked then value in cell change on “vacation”. If checkbox is unchecked then value in cell go back to previous value.  The screenshot visually shows what should happen. I’m newbie and can’t find solution. I will be very grateful if someone helps me in any way. [Screenshot](https://paste.pics/1543d1be3e087321c4ccb236931e9f44)

I apologize that I did not accurately state the essence of the question, function "IF" is not suitable since the second condition is dynamic, like this week the specialist works on one schedule (8-11), and next week on a different schedule (it can be any)
it would be great if the "if" function worked like this
=IF(H1=TRUE,"vacation","return the previous value")

Answer (score 0):

```
=IF(H1=TRUE,"vacation","8-11")
```

Comment: I apologize that I did not accurately state the essence of the question, function "IF" is not suitable since the second condition is dynamic, like this week the specialist works on one schedule (8-11), and next week on a different schedule (it can be any)

Comment: @Roman Please pay attention while reviewing. This is not a "link-only" answer. Although code-only answers are considered a poor answer, it is still an answer, which means at most you should downvote them, but not delete them.

Comment: @Mr.Omich You have clarified your question and now it is clear that the value in the cell is dynamic. In order to answer the question, it would be nice to know how the value in this cell changes. Would you like to share a sample of your sheet?

Comment: https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1o1cxsWWnKHe4CP4JBND5ZidPJ1IAZtjVgZYb_FTpDgg/edit?usp=sharing
The values in the cells are the time of the doctor's appointment, this value is set by the doctor himself, depending on his schedule. If next week he will not conduct the reception, he writes vacation with his hands in each cell, I would like to insert the value vacation in each cell by pressing one button, if you press the button again, the graph of the previous week is returned.  I think that such a task is not for Google Sheets, perhaps some special software is needed

Comment: The second condition would be dynamic if changed using a formula or script. However, this is not the case for you, it is changed manually. Therefore, the user can also manually change the time in the formula and everything works well. I showed this in your example worksheet.

Answer (score 0):

Or you can go to Data Validation and create your own rules like this.

This is how I did mine:

[image]

I wanted to make my checkboxes for money management and so if I have a checkbox checked then the value means say $100 and I can play with the value $100 instead of the value TRUE.